# GL_REPLACE with a fragment shader?

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

How can i emulate legacy opengls texenv gl_replace mode using es 2?
Basically, if the texture fragments alpha is 0, i want to use the primitives color. But otherwise not affect the fragments color. 
Im new to glsl and could use the help.

Im on android and ive already got textures working with transparency.
And i want to use just one shader program.  What ive got:
gl_FragColor=texture2D(u_TextureUnit,v_TextureCoords);
And id like to add a color to the primitive that only shows up where the texture is transparent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This snippet will output a blend between the vertex colour and the texture colour, controlled by the texture alpha, which I think is what you wanted. If not, please try to describe in more precise terms what your inputs and desired outputs are.

```
lowp vec4 vPrimitiveCol = colour_from_vertex_passed_as_varying;
lowp vec4 vTexCol = texture2D(u_TextureUnit,v_TextureCoords);
gl_FragColor.rgb = mix(vPrimitiveCol.rgb, vTexCol.rgb, vTexCol.a);
gl_FragColor.a = 1.0;
```

Comment: Awesome thank you! Works perfectly though i do not understand it. At all :/

Answer (score 0):

What you want isn't `GL_REPLACE` which would completely replace the fragment color. It sounds more like `GL_BLEND`. Anyway, you can emulate it using the GLSL mix function:

```
solid_color = ...;
tex_color = texture(texture_sampler, texture_coord);
gl_FragColor = mix(solid_color, tex_color, tex_color.a);
```

Note that I replaced the older `texture2D` function by the more recent (and recommended) generic type `texture` function.

Comment: Is `texture` supported in GL ES 2 ? As the OP mentions this environment

Comment: `texture()` is an OpenGL ES 3 feature.

Comment: @rotoglup: The question has been tagged very broadly, thus I answered broadly and opted to point out, that I used the generalized form.

Comment: I think i might have meant gl_modulate, but whatever, its workin now. Thanks for your answer though i didnt need to try it